# WPF ListBox/View Data Binding weird result

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I have this problem when i try to synchronize a observable list with listbox/view
it displays the first item  X times (x total amount of records in the list)
but it doesn't change the variable's

here is the XAML

```
   <ListBox x:Name="PostListView" BorderThickness="0"
                  MinHeight="300" 
                  Background="{x:Null}"
                  BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                  Foreground="{x:Null}"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PostListData}}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  MinWidth="332" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionMode="Extended" AlternationCount="1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <DockPanel x:Name="SinglePost" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ClipToBounds="True" Width="333" Height="70" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment" d:IsEffectDisabled="True">
            <DockPanel.DataContext>
                <local:PostList/>
            </DockPanel.DataContext>
            <StackPanel x:Name="AvatarNickHolder" Width="60">
                            <Label x:Name="Nick" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="15" Content="{Binding Path=pUsername, FallbackValue=pUsername}" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="10.667" Padding="5,0"/>
                <Image x:Name="Avatar" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50" IsHitTestVisible="False" Source="1045443356IMG_0972.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="userPostText" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10.667" Text="{Binding Path=pMsg, FallbackValue=pMsg}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and here is the ovservable list class

```
  public class PostList : ObservableCollection<PostData>
    {
        public PostList()
            : base()
        {
            Add(new PostData("this is test msg", "Cather", "1045443356IMG_0972.jpg"));
            Add(new PostData("this is test msg1", "t1", "1045443356IMG_0972.jpg"));
            Add(new PostData("this is test msg2", "t2", "1045443356IMG_0972.jpg"));
            Add(new PostData("this is test msg3", "t3", "1045443356IMG_0972.jpg"));
            Add(new PostData("this is test msg4", "t4", "1045443356IMG_0972.jpg"));
            Add(new PostData("this is test msg5", "t5", "1045443356IMG_0972.jpg"));
           // Add(new PostData("Isak", "Dinesen"));
          //  Add(new PostData("Victor", "Hugo"));
          //  Add(new PostData("Jules", "Verne"));
        }
    }

    public class PostData
    {
        private string Username;
        private string Msg;
        private string Avatar;
        private string LinkAttached;
        private string PicAttached;
        private string VideoAttached;

        public PostData(string msg ,string username, string avatar=null, string link=null,string pic=null ,string video=null)
        {
            this.Username = username;
            this.Msg = msg;
            this.Avatar = avatar;
            this.LinkAttached = link;
            this.PicAttached = pic;
            this.VideoAttached = video;
        }

        public string pMsg
        {
            get { return Msg; }
            set { Msg = value; }
        }

        public string pUsername
        {
            get { return Username; }
            set { Username = value; }
        }

        public string pAvatar
        {
            get { return Avatar; }
            set { Avatar = value; }
        }

        public string pLink
        {
            get { return LinkAttached; }
            set { LinkAttached = value; }
        }

        public string pPic
        {
            get { return PicAttached; }
            set { PicAttached = value; }
        }

        public string pVideo
        {
            get { return VideoAttached; }
            set { VideoAttached = value; }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new DataContext (PostList) every time a template is created.

In the ListBox, set the ItemsSource to a new PostList.

The ListBox will assign each instance of PostData to each copy of the DataTemplate and set it as the DataContext of the root element.

tl;dr:  Get rid of

```
<DockPanel.DataContext>
    <local:PostList/>
</DockPanel.DataContext>
```

Comment: and now it doesn't synchronize , i add dynamically an item and it won't appear :( i'm newbie :(

Comment: @avia You're probably adding the item to what you believe is the PostList that the control is bound against, but in fact is NOT the same instance.  I'd definitely suggest you create a very simple project that binds a single ListBox to a single ObservableCollection in order to learn how everything works together.